# Running into cURL error with S3 class on local machine but runs fine on host

Tags: php, apache, curl, amazon-s3, localhost

I'm completely lost on this, I'm not sure what is causing this error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'cURL_Exception' with message 'cURL resource: Resource id #17; cURL error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (cURL error code 60). See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html for an explanation of error codes.' in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\htdocs\TestSite\src_ama\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php:824 Stack trace: #0 C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\htdocs\TestSite\src_ama\services\s3.class.php(903): RequestCore->send_request() #1 C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\htdocs\TestSite\src_ama\services\s3.class.php(1625): AmazonS3->authenticate('mybucket', Array) #2 C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\htdocs\TestSite\class_SysFunc.php(794): AmazonS3->list_objects('mybucket', Array) #3 C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\htdocs\TestSite\sub_dashOverview.php(26): SysFunc->getCartonSize('1.41c388ab584f1...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\htdocs\TestSite\src_ama\lib\requestcore\requestcore.class.php on line 824

The way I have this setup in my website, I have a class in which I use to connect to S3 and it works perfectly fine on my host account.

**class.php**

```
    if(!class_exists('SysFunc')){
        class SysFunc{
            var $s3;
            var $bucket = 'mybucket';

            function __construct() {
                require_once ('amazon/sdk.class.php');
                $this->s3 = new AmazonS3();
            }

            ...More functions
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering if it has to do with my php.ini file or possibly the Apache config file.

Any ideas would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your local CA files are likely broken. If you have access to the actual curl handle, try this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);.

EDIT: In AWS, try $s3->disable_ssl_verification();

Comment: Hey David, thx for your response. When you say CA files, what files are you referring to? Also where would I locate the curl handle?.. And I tried **$s3->disable_ssl_verification();** in my class, now I get this warning: _Disabling the verification of SSL certificates can lead to man-in-the-middle attacks._ But I believe I can turn off the warnings.

Comment: The certificate authority (SSL) files on your system. Yes, that warning message is accurate but for a dev system I doubt it matters that much (I could be wrong...).

Comment: Ok, I'll check it out. I turned off the warnings and things seem to be running fine. Thanks again!

Comment: `$s3->disable_ssl_verification();` worked for me. But I lso needed to do `error_reporting(E_WARNING);`

Answer (score 2):

Open the config file for the Amazon SDK

It's the one where you filled in your access key and secret key and its called config.inc.php

near the bottom is an option 'certificate_authority' which by default is set to false.. Just set it to true and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when I changed the permission on the local folder where I was uploading the file it all magically worked. change the permission to 777.